# expand/collapse CardView in RecyclerView with animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-cardview

i try to using this animation [folding-cell](https://github.com/Ramotion/folding-cell-android)

I need it in a RecyclerView as Cardview, all running amazing but if i try to expand/collapse one card, he expand/collapse more of it.I do not know if casually and how, but I do not expand/collapse one card at a time.
This is the code of my Adapter:

```
public class AllCorsiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AllCorsiAdapter.ScanViewHolder>{
    private List<MainActivity.Corso> corsiList;
    private Context context;
    // avatar
    private String emptyAvatar = "@drawable/contruction";
    private int imageRes;
    public AllCorsiAdapter(List<MainActivity.Corso> corsiList, Context context) {
        this.corsiList = corsiList;
        this.context = context;
     }
     @Override
     public ScanViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_card, null);
        ScanViewHolder scanViewHolder = new ScanViewHolder(view);
        return scanViewHolder;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ScanViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MainActivity.Corso corso = corsiList.get(position);
        holder.tvNomeCorsoT.setText(corso.getNome());
        holder.tvNomeCorsoC.setText(corso.getNome());
        holder.tvInfo.setText(corso.getDay()+", " + corso.getHr());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return corsiList.size();
    }
    public static class ScanViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView tvNomeCorsoT;
        TextView tvNomeCorsoC;
        TextView tvInfo;
        ImageView ivCoverT;
        ImageView ivCoverC;
        CardView card;
        FoldingCell fc;

        public ScanViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvNomeCorsoT = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_corsoname_title);
            tvNomeCorsoC = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_corsoname_content);
            tvInfo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_infoCorso);
            card = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvSingleCorso);
            fc = (FoldingCell) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foldingCell);
            fc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    fc.toggle(false);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is my cardview .xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvSingleCorso"
    android:layout_width="355dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#edf7f9"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="7dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp">
    <com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:folding-cell="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/foldingCell"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        folding-cell:animationDuration="1300"
        folding-cell:cameraHeight="20"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true">

        <!-- CONTENT (UNFOLDED) LAYOUT (MUST BE AT LEAST 2x times BIGGER than content layout bellow)-->
        <include
            layout="@layout/cell_content_layout"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            tools:ignore="IncludeLayoutParam" />

        <!-- TITLE (FOLDED) LAYOUT (MUST BE AT LEAST 2x times SMALLER than content layout above) -->
        <include layout="@layout/cell_title_layout" />

    </com.ramotion.foldingcell.FoldingCell>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think the problem is in this part of code:

```
fc = (FoldingCell) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foldingCell);
fc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fc.toggle(false);
    }
});
```

In mainActivity.java i just use this,in for loop, to create cards:

```
...
// cardView
corsiList.add(new Corso(nome,giorno,orario,cover));
...
RecyclerView recyclerViewScan = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvAllCorsi);
recyclerViewScan.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
AllCorsiAdapter allCorsiAdapter = new AllCorsiAdapter(corsiList,MainActivity.this);
recyclerViewScan.setAdapter(allCorsiAdapter);
....
```

I've tried everything and tried online too, but no one seems to have ever had my problem.

Comment: brother can you help me in installing this library in my android project. I am facing difficulty please I shall be very thankful if you help me in deploying this library in my android project.

Comment: just add this (com.ramotion.foldingcell:folding-cell:1.2.2) into your graddle:app